# How long should I wait until I put new jars in?

Tags: canning

Currently canning some banana peppers. I have a large stock pot set up with a 3 jar canning rack. I just finished a round of jars in the stock pot and the water was boiling. How cool should I let the water get before I put the next round of jars in to start heating up? I don't want to break my jars by putting them into the pot when its too hot.

I realize this is an inefficient way to do this, but I don't have another pot big enough to heat my jars (the only other one that is close currently has my hot vinegar solution in it).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Preheat the jars with hot tap water, and then just dump them in the boiling water (with tongs or other appropriate utensil, of course).

Comment: Didn't have a chance to come back the other day, but this worked perfectly, no broken jars and they seemed to seal just fine